# Embedded Video - Iframe - YouTube - Won't autoplay

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, iframe, youtube

YouTube videos are being embedded at the top of single posts. However, the [autoplay](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?csw=1#autoplay) does not work.

The video is being embedded with Toolkit Types and I have set [autoplay to on](https://wp-types.com/documentation/functions/#audio). This should work on both audio files and [embedded media](https://wp-types.com/documentation/functions/#embedded-media).

However, the autoplay does not work.

```
<div>
    <?php $renderfieldmedia = types_render_field('film', array('raw'=>'true'))?>
    <?php if(!empty($renderfieldmedia)){?>
        <div id="videoholder">
            <dd><?php echo(types_render_field('film', array("output" => "html", "autoplay" => "on"))); ?></dd>
        </div>
    <?php } elseif(empty($renderfieldmedia)){?>     
    <?php }?>               
</div>
```

**I have tried the following:**

1. Checking for errors
2. Deactivate almost all WordPress plugins
3. Remove almost all JS

Still nothing.

If any help, the page can be found [here](http://higraf.no/portfolio/fotoprosjekt-2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<div>
<?php $renderfieldmedia = types_render_field('film', array('raw'=>'true'))?>
<?php if(!empty($renderfieldmedia)){?>
    <div id="videoholder">
        <dd><?php echo(types_render_field('film', array("output" => "html", "autoplay" => "1"))); ?></dd>
    </div>
<?php } elseif(empty($renderfieldmedia)){?>     
<?php }?>
```

autoplay = 1

Visit
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Manual_IFrame_Embeds